I received ETH meta coinbase says its fake sender says its not?
So I have a coinbase wallet that received ethm.  Coinbase support stated that the ethm in the wallet wasn't authentic.   How can I prove it is or it isn't.   The sender says it's valid,  coinbase support says no.  I have the hashtag address.   But I am very unfamiliar with virtual currency. I linked my coinbase ethm account to uniswap but it shows 0 balance.  Who is right coinbase or sender? How do I verify?

What is "ethm"? Some token? Should it have value? Please provide the relevant hashes: transaction hash at least

It is worth noting that anyone can issue tokens, and whether any token is real depends on whether someone in the market recognizes it. The simple judgment of whether the market recognizes it is that there are quotes on decentralized exchanges such as Uniswap or centralized exchanges such as Binance. If there are, it must be real.
In fact, ethm is a new token that I have not seen. mETH may be correct. This is the Mantle LSP staking protocol token.
